# How to redirect visitors to the server that is closest to them and where to place the servers?

Tags: web-hosting

I am focusing on providing fast page refreshes for my visitors and I wonder where is the smartest spot to place my servers on?

I understand that the best would be to place a server in every country or even city, but that is of course not doable with my economy. I am thinking of maybe setting up three servers, one in the middle of USA (Kansas?), one in Italy and one in Sweden. What do you think about that? I don't care about Africa since they haven't even got computers so I won't get traffic from there anyway. China, North Korea etc are probably just visiting chinese websites, they barely know english anway...

The next problem is how do I redirect a visitor from Finland to the Swedish server? I don't want the visitor from Finland to be using the USA server or vice versa.

Comment: I downvoted you for being racist

Comment: I think it would be advisable to educate yourself about other countries before looking at such solutions. Over 150 million people have internet in Africa and over 11 million people in China speak 'English' and this is not counting those who can read English which will be far more.

Answer (score 1):

If having servers close to your visitors is very important to your business, then you should looking into using a [Content Delivery Network (CDN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

A company that runs a CDN has a large number of servers distributed around the globe.  They use DNS tricks to direct visitors to the nearest server.   The CDN servers will generally fetch content from your central server and cache it on the edge nodes to speed up content delivery.

Rather than build such a network yourself, it is usually cost effective to employ the services of a company that has already built such a network.

Comment: But I am not planning on any huge networks here. I want the access time for the website to be max 1.5s in Europe and USA. Then I guess one server in USA and two servers in Europe is enough?

Comment: You can explore the plans & pricing of CDNs offered by Cloud service providers like Amazon (http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/) and Microsoft (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/cdn/) and even dedicated CDN providers before setting up servers on your own.